# how to decode a hashed token to get the original token in golang

Tags: go, email, authentication, hash

i've got this piece of code which I'm wanting to use to create a token which will be stored and then create a hashed version of this token to send it out to the client for email verification.

The issue is that I don't know how to decrypt the hashed token to give me the original token.
Can someone please help me out?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

// GenerateToken returns a unique token based on the provided email string
func GenerateToken(email string) string {
    hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(email), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

fmt.Println("Hash to store:", string(hash))

hasher := md5.New()
hasher.Write(hash)
return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("token:", GenerateToken("bob@webserver.com"))
}
```

Comment: You can’t. Hashing is one-way. There is no way to get the original data back, and there’s infinite inputs that would give the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing encryption with hashing.

When encrypting data you are able to decrypt it to the original value. This is not possible when hashing.

When working with hashes, rather than trying to 'dehash' the token, you should instead hash the original value and compare the hashed output with the provided token.

Take the following example: https://go.dev/play/p/7F22cFZBqbh

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func HashValue(v string) string {
    hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(v), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(hashedPassword)
}

func CompareToHash(v, hash string) bool {
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hash), []byte(v))
    return err == nil
}

func main() {
    password := "my-password"
    hashedPassword := HashValue(password)

    validPassword := "my-password"
    invalidPassword := "not-my-password"

    // Instead of unhashing 'hashedPassword', we instead hash the raw string and compare the hash

    fmt.Println(CompareToHash(validPassword, hashedPassword))   // true
    fmt.Println(CompareToHash(invalidPassword, hashedPassword)) // false
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `subtle.ConstantTimeCompare` instead of `==`, due to timing-attack. That is also used internally by BCrypt (`CompareHashAndPassword`).

Comment: @Inkeliz I updated to answer to use `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword`